# Why is there no Shared Memory Bank conflict when loading consecutive half floats or vectorized int4?

Tags: memory, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I expect a cuda shared memory bank conflict in the following two situations:

- Accessing successive half floats (2 words) with successive threads
- Accessing vectorized int4 datatypes by successive threads

A tabular representation of the shared memory banks and the memory access in the two situations is:

| Banks | 0 | 1 | ... | 15 | 16 | .. | 31 | 0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TwoBanks | 0, 1 | 2, 3 |  | 30, 31 | - |  | - | - |
| Vectorized | 0 | 0 |  | 3 | 4 |  | 7 | 8 |

When accessing half floats, two threads should compete for the first 16 memory banks. When accessing int4s, 4 threads should compete for 4 banks each. However, nisght-compute tells me there are no conflicts.

To illustrate, consider the following program (available on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/6Ks5aTK87)):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda_fp16.h>

using T = half;

__global__ void TwoBanks(T* sum) {
    __shared__ T shmem[32];
    shmem[threadIdx.x] = (T)threadIdx.x;
    __syncthreads();
    T accum{0};
    *sum = accum; // set to zero
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
        accum += shmem[i];
    }
    *sum = accum;
}

__global__ void Vectorized(T* sum) {
    __shared__ T shmem[32 * 8];
    T write[8];
    for (uint i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        write[i] = static_cast<T>(threadIdx.x) + static_cast<T>(i);
    }
    T* dst = shmem + threadIdx.x * 8;
    reinterpret_cast<int4*>(dst)[0] = reinterpret_cast<int4*>(write)[0];
    __syncthreads();
    T accum{0};
    *sum = accum; // set to zero
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 32 * 8; ++i) {
        accum += shmem[i];
    }
    *sum = accum;
}

int main() {
    dim3 GridDim(32);
    dim3 BlockDim(1);
    constexpr size_t sz = sizeof(T);
    T* device_sum;
    T host_sum[1];
    cudaMalloc((void**)&device_sum, sz);
    TwoBanks<<<BlockDim, GridDim>>>(device_sum);
    cudaMemcpy(host_sum, device_sum, sz, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    std::cout << "The sum for TwoBanks is: " << (float)host_sum[0] << std::endl;
    Vectorized<<<BlockDim, GridDim>>>(device_sum);
    cudaMemcpy(host_sum, device_sum, sz, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    std::cout << "The sum for Vectorized: " << (float)host_sum[0] << std::endl;
}
```

When I run the program with nsight-compute, I am told there are no conflicts:

```
    Section: Command line profiler metrics
    -------------------------------------------------------- ----------- ------------
    Metric Name                                              Metric Unit Metric Value
    -------------------------------------------------------- ----------- ------------
    l1tex__data_bank_conflicts_pipe_lsu_mem_shared_op_ld.sum                        0
    l1tex__data_bank_conflicts_pipe_lsu_mem_shared_op_st.sum                        0
    -------------------------------------------------------- ----------- ------------

  Vectorized(__half *) (1, 1, 1)x(32, 1, 1), Context 1, Stream 7, Device 0, CC 7.5
    Section: Command line profiler metrics
    -------------------------------------------------------- ----------- ------------
    Metric Name                                              Metric Unit Metric Value
    -------------------------------------------------------- ----------- ------------
    l1tex__data_bank_conflicts_pipe_lsu_mem_shared_op_ld.sum                        0
    l1tex__data_bank_conflicts_pipe_lsu_mem_shared_op_st.sum                        0
    -------------------------------------------------------- ----------- ------------
```

What's wrong with my analysis?

Comment: What's your GPU?

Comment: Related: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/float4-shared-memory-doesnt-yield-bank-conflict-according-to-nvprof-when-it-should/47557

Comment: @Homer512: Thanks for your reply. This was profiled on a Quadro T1000.

Comment: Re: Half Float: Could the [following explanation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html?highlight=bank%20conflict#shared-memory-5-x) be relevant: "A shared memory request for a warp does not generate a bank conflict between two threads that access any address within the same 32-bit word (even though the two addresses fall in the same bank)." ?

Comment: It certainly looks like the hardware has undocumented capabilities that allow it to handle its native types and vector types efficiently. Turing has a unified shared memory and L1 cache. I wonder if this style of architecture helps with this, since the subsystem already needs the capability to deal with coalesced global memory accesses

Comment: The first case is clear as you have cited. The second one should take multiple transactions but probably doesn't count as a conflict because there is no way of moving that amount of data in less transactions. I.e. it is only a conflict if you get less than ideal number of transactions / throughput due to it.

Comment: Thanks @paleonix: That's very interesting. Do you have an official source for " it is only a conflict if you get less than ideal number of transactions / throughput"?

Comment: @paleonix I came up with this benchmark: https://godbolt.org/z/z6653GrGx My T1200 can handle both codes with the same runtime performance and doesn't report bank conflicts. I certainly don't get the 50% drop which I get when modifying the code to provoke an actual bank conflict.